# Developing Outlook Add-In which Outlook Add-In version should I select in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing my first Outlook Add-In in C#. In Visual Studio I have the options to develop an "Outlook 2010 Add-in" or "Outlook 2013 Add-in" or probably an "Outlook 2016 Add-in".

This Add-In should work on one PC which runs currently Outlook 2010 but which I could upgrade to a newer version.

If I start to develop an "Outlook 2010 Add-in" will this also work in Outlook 2013 and 2016? Do I have to do something to make it work with different versions of Outlook?

My Add-In will check some details of the mails and depending on the details it will sort these mails. I guess that should work in all versions.

Is there a clear advantage of an 2013 or 2016 Add-In compared to 2010?

Comment: If it works the same way as SharePoint, they won't be backward compatibility. Upgrading it might be just as simple as upgrading the solution and redeploy. Obviously latest version will have more features with their API. Your best bet is to test it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks @penleychan. Obviously I could test it. But there must be many people who did this before me and like to share their experience.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by @penleychan, targeting the latest version is a good thought. I did the same when I develop my VSTO addin. Most of the time I have used the common features of the Outlook and developed the addin with template version similar to the installed office (on my machine). Its easy to debug.

If the addin is going use specific feature(s) of a version of Office, then we should use that version template.

You may like to refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Office 2010 based solution in later Office versions. You just need to choose the right target .net version. Read more about that in the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

> Is there a clear advantage of an 2013 or 2016 Add-In compared to 2010?

The only benefit you get in that case - the PIAs version corresponding to the target Office version. That means you will get access to objects, methods, properties and events available in later Office versions. Anyway, at runtime you still can use the late-binding technology which allows accessing missed members at design-time. See [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.